# How to start using Minio without accessKey and secretKey?

Tags: minio

I have a minio server running on debian using SystemD and proxied with NGINX and secured with Let's Encrypt. In the docs it suggests the service is comparable to Amazon S3 but I can't figure out how to actually use the service.

```
Version: 2019-03-27T22:35:21Z
Release-Tag: RELEASE.2019-03-27T22-35-21Z
Commit-ID: 6df05e489dc789cf26e82810cf5cfeefb1d90761
```

It looks like in order to create a bucket or use the minio cli `mc` there needs to be a registered TARGET along with accessKey and secretKey. I can't find anywhere on the server where that information is available and it's not clear to me how to create a new target.

Here is the `/etc/default/minio` file:

```
MINIO_VOLUMES="/usr/local/share/minio"
MINIO_OPTS="-C /etc/minio --address :9000"
```

There are no files in `/etc/minio`.

It's running and set up, but how can I start actually using the minio server?

---

Edit: Config JSON

I tried creating a new config file and entering new `accessKey` and `secretKey` in the `credential` field. I was not able to sign in to the Minio Browser app using the same keys.

---

Edit: Key Files

I tried entering a new access key and secret key into the files `/etc/minio/access_key` and `/etc/minio/secret_key` and adding the following lines to the `/etc/default/minio` environment file:

```
MINIO_ACCESS_KEY_FILE="/etc/minio/access_key"
MINIO_SECRET_KEY_FILE="/etc/minio/secret_key"
```

I restarted the service `systemctl restart minio` but I still can't log into the Minio Browser app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only worked to provide `MINIO_ACCESS_KEY` and `MINIO_SECRET_KEY` into `/etc/default/minio` environment file. Every other method failed.

I used the following to generate a secret key that resemble AWS access keys in the example. In the CLI help text it looks like access key and secret key would work however.

```
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(30)
```